# How to parse a BufferedInputStream with DocumentBuilder without getting the stream closed?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an `BufferedInputStream` that represents and XML file, but I'm not sure what the schema is. So, what I'd like to do is parse the XML, explore the DOM to determine which XML format/schema it is in dynamically, and then `reset()` the stream, and then pass the stream to the appropriate parsing library.

However, it seems that the `DocumentBuilder` is closing the `BufferedInputStream` for me. How do I prevent this? Is there an API way of preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I've been able to come up with:

1. [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) my 'real' `BufferedInputStream` with an implementation that will not propagate the `close()` command to the 'real' `BufferedInputStream` (but will propagate all the others methods)
2. pass the decorated `BufferedInputStream` to the `DocumentBuilder`.
3. `reset()` my 'real' `BufferedInputStream`.
4. `close()` the 'real' when I am ready.

Better answers welcome since I'd rather do it via API than through this.

Comment: I would decorate the `BufferedInputStream` with an implementation that iteratively stores the bytes it reads into a `byte[]`. Close the stream normally. Then call `getBytes()` and pass a `ByteArrayInputStream` with those bytes to the `DocumentBuilder`. This is an issue if you don't have much memory, but you save reading from the file twice.